# extracting position of selected text in pdf file

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I've a question. I need in my wpf application to open a pdf file (I think best solution is a webbrowser), highlighting a phrase, clicking a button and extracting position (coordinates into pdf) of phrase that I selected in the pdf file.
I need exact coordinates of phrase into pdf. How can I proceed?What could be best solution?Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find x,y location of a text in pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740157/how-to-find-x-y-location-of-a-text-in-pdf)

Comment: @PaulZahra *possible duplicate of...* -  I don't think so: The OP wants the exact position of text highlighted in some PDF viewer while the question you linked to is about coordinates of text extracted from a PDF without GUI intervention.